# When training my model in tensorflow I can't see progress outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training a model for speech recognition however I can't show the output progress when training the model.

my code

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import automatic_speech_recognition as asr

dataset = asr.dataset.Audio.from_csv('test.csv', batch_size=1)
dev_dataset = asr.dataset.Audio.from_csv('test.csv', batch_size=1)
alphabet = asr.text.Alphabet(lang='en')
features_extractor = asr.features.FilterBanks(
    features_num=160,
    winlen=0.02,
    winstep=0.01,
    winfunc=np.hanning
)
model = asr.model.get_deepspeech2(
    input_dim=160,
    output_dim=29,
    rnn_units=800,
    is_mixed_precision=False
)
optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(
    lr=1e-4,
    beta_1=0.9,
    beta_2=0.999,
    epsilon=1e-8
)
decoder = asr.decoder.GreedyDecoder()
pipeline = asr.pipeline.CTCPipeline(
    alphabet, features_extractor, model, optimizer, decoder
)
pipeline.fit(dataset, dev_dataset, epochs=5)
pipeline.save('/checkpoint')
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but I think you'r missing "verbose" which takes values 0-2, 0 shows nothing while 1 shows the bar progress and 2 shows the number of epochs.

try:

```
pipeline.fit(dataset, dev_dataset, epochs=5, verbose=1)
```